# Accessing Ui elements inside method in fragment,shows null pointer exception in android

Tags: android

I have two fragments.with one fragment,I am replacing the second fragment with another dynamically.calling the method in new fragment from first fragment. The method in new fragment set texts for the ui elements accessing in oncreateView methoid.but not accessed It shows null pointer exception.

code is:

```
public class MachinesForm extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

  TextView ws_name, ws_info, last_update, engine_hours, model_num, ser_num,

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fleet_machineinfo, null);
    Log.d("", ""+v);
    ws_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_info);
    ws_info = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_quickinfo);
    return v;
  }

  void setting_machineinfo(int wid, String mid) {
    c = DBAdapter.getMacinfowithws(wid, mid);
    c_hours = DBAdapter.getLastHoursValuesOfMachine(mid);
    c.moveToFirst();
    c_hours.moveToFirst();
    name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("WS_Name"));
    System.out.println("name: " + name);//i got name
    Log.d("",""+ws_name);
    ws_name.setText(name); //here shows nullpointer exception
    System.out.println("ok");
  }
}
```